# How to convert string into list?

Tags: python

Well, I am using python. And I have case here.

from my api. The following key and value is coming.

```
games : ["['football','cricket']"]
```

Now i want to get that football and cricket from coming games value and store in python list.

expected output:

```
print(games) ==> ["football","circket"]
print(type(games))  ==> <class list>
```

Comment: Perhaps `ast.literal_eval` function would be useful here.  Just pass the string into the function and a list of strings will be returned. [Docs linked here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: the following StackOverflow question can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list

Comment: Just use `json.loads()`. Highly unlikely that any api is sending any other than json string.

Comment: json.loads returns error on this value. I used that first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `ast.literal_eval` function would be useful here. Just pass the string into the function and a list of strings will be returned.

This will be more robust that trying to manipulate the string, as the function is designed to ingest (if you will) key Python data structures as strings; perform a bit of validation to ensure the string is not malicious, and output the associated object.

- [Docs linked here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)
- [Source code linked here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/ast.py#L54)

For example:

```
import ast

games = ["['football','cricket']"]

ast.literal_eval(games[0])
```

Output:

```
['football','cricket']
```

Comment: This is a good and quite general solution. +1 from me

Comment: This is really easy and to the point answer. I'm really thankful to guys like you who are here to help newbie like me.

Comment: @dummyfirst - My pleasure.  We all continue to learn together.

Comment: What I like about this is: it would work even in more complex scenarios - for example, in nested lists like `"['football','cricket', ['tennis', 'basketball']]"`. Stripping/replacing characters - while it works for the specific example - could be a recipe for disasters.

Comment: yeah i tested that and it worked perfectly. I guess i need to study what ast. and how does it perform this job.

Comment: @dummyfirst - Interesting you should mention the ‘how it works’.  I’ve just updated the answer to include a link to the source code so you can study it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```py
a = ["['football','cricket']"]
out = [val.strip("'") for val in a[0].strip("[|]").split(",")]
print(out)
```

```
['football', 'cricket']
```

Comment: Your solution worked but its seems like quite complicated. The upper answer is seems more easy. but I really appreciate you spent time in answering. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I find it unlikely that a api is sending a non-json string.  This string is not json because of the single quotes. If you convert them to double quotes, you have a valid json.

```
list_games = json.loads(games[0].replace("'",'"'))
```

Comment: this one is also a simple and helpful answer. And You're right the json need to be valid. I appreciate man.!